# Solaris Clusters - cluster: (C383355) No response from daemon on node

Tags: cluster, solaris, failover, failovercluster, solaris-10

I followed the [instructions here](http://www.unixarena.com/2014/06/configure-solaris-two-node-cluster-solaris-10.html) to setup 2 node solaris cluster

At the end of everything I noticed that one of the node's status is "offline"

I also see the following message from "# cluster status"

```
cluster:  (C383355) No response from daemon on node "<node_name>".
```

Anyone know how to bring this node online? Thanks in advance!